# Android app update broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

So, im working on something that requires me to know when another application on the device is being updated. So my question is quite simple, does lets say YouTube or Spotify send a broadcast when the application is updating, and if so, what do i need to catch with my broadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your intent filter should be like:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
   <data android:scheme="package" />
</intent-filter>
```

And onReceive method from your BroadcastReceiver should be:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Uri data = intent.getData();
    if (data.toString().equals("package:" + "com.target.package") {
        // action to do
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the other answer that is using `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` as well

Comment: @kingston Why? Doesn't belong to the question.

Answer (score 7):

> According to android docs: 
>   **Broadcast Action**: A new version of your application has been installed over an existing one.  This is only sent to the application that was replaced.  It does not contain any additional data; to receive it, just use an intent filter for this action.

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
   <data android:scheme="package" />
</intent-filter>
```

And onReceive method from your BroadcastReceiver should be:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // action to do

}
```

Comment: I believe the correct answer would be removing: `<data android:scheme="package" />` and keep the rest as is - found that on another thread here and seems to work.

Comment: @Ben, you are right, `<data android:scheme="package" />` should be removed

Comment: The question was about "know when another application on the device is being updated".

Answer (score 4):

[ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED) is action triggered when an application is being updated
According to docs :

> A new version of an application package has been installed, replacing
>   an existing version that was previously installed. The data contains
>   the name of the package.

`intent.getPackage()` returns the package/application this intent was specifically addressed to but it was sent to any interested receiver, therefore, there isn't such package.

Use `intent.getData()` which returns the updated package as an Uri

Add the below intent filter while registering a broadcast receiver in your Manifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
   <data android:scheme="package" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: will this work for your own app ? will the broadcast receiver be executed if your app has been updated ?

Comment: @RobertEstivill just tested. It will.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work when I updated own app.