# Detection of old version application on Android

Tags: android

I am going to put new version of my application in Google Play. What is the best way to detect that there is installed on phone old version of application?

Please note that I would to detect that old version of my application was installed. Please note, that my application is installed on phones and I have no information about version ( I didn't think that I would distribute a new version).

Comment: You don't have to. Google Play will update all older version of your app, giving that your version code is higher than the previous APK you uploaded

Comment: I mean something else. I would like to detect that old version is installed on my phone ( or was installed- during installation a new version, the old was uninstalled)

Comment: Take look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30727953/4350275

Comment: unless there is already a mechanism in the app to identify it as being installed, there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

I used to send the versionAPP to the server when users try to login, later I compare that version with a currently version saved in database.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get information about, you can do it inside the developer console.

Log into your developer account.
There are graphs and infos that show everything you want to know.

Select your app, and there you can see installations by phone model, Android version and **app version**.

See more about it [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en).

Comment: I would like to detect it in my new version of app.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have a method to store version code, then this approach should work :

Firstly get the **current version code** as follows, in `onCreate()` method :

```
public int versionCode;
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
versionCode = pInfo.versionCode;
```

Add code to save **current version code** as follows, in the `onStop()` method :

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putInt("version_code", versionCode);
editor.commit();
```

Then get **previous version code** as follows, in the `onCreate()` method itself :

```
public int prevVersionCode = -1;

SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
int prevVersionCode = sp.getInt("version_code", -1);

if(prevVersionCode == -1) {
    // this will happen on a previous app version
}
```

if **prevVersionCode equals -1** , this means that this was an old version of app that has been updated.

if **prevVersionCode is not equal to -1** , this means that the version from which the app has just been updated was a version newer than the one where this saving code was added.

Now you can easily compare between versions by using **versionCode** and **prevVersionCode**, just note that if **prevVersionCode equals -1**, it means that previously the app was on a version that didn't have the storing method, but now it has been updated to a newer version.

**For example :** Suppose the app is currently on versionCode 13 and you add this code and post an update with versionCode 14. So when users update the app, the **prevVersionCode will be equal to -1** and you can do wahatever you want to do. **versionCode will be equal to 14, but prevVersionCode will give -1, only on FIRST RUN**. On restart both **versionCode** and **prevVersionCode** will give **14**.
Now Suppose you update your app further and post an update with versionCode 15. Now on the **first run** of updated app, **versionCode will give 15, but prevVersionCode will give 14**. But after restarting **both** will give 15.