# Restarting a service upon app update from playstore

Tags: android, android-service, android-update-app

My android app makes use of a service which is currently triggered if the app is opened (and service is currently not running), or if device is rebooted.

When I released the first update on Google Play I noticed that on updating the app from Google play on a device, the functionalities of the app as set through my service **stopped working** until I open the app once or reboot my device.

I hence put a message on Google Play asking all my current users using those functionalities to reopen the app for the functionalities to start working again.

Now I am planning to release another update for my app, but this time, I would somehow like to *either make the service persist upon app update* **or** *restart the service on app update* **without forcing any user action**, so that existing users will not experience any problems in using my app.

Any solutions with/ without code would be appreciated.

Comment: The PackageManager sends broadcasts for app updates. Particularly, `android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` intent broadcast can be used to get a notification when your app gets updated. You can receive this broadcast from your service / app and restart your service based on that. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727953/android-app-update-broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

As user iVoid comments you can listen for the `android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` intent. Create a `BroadcastReceiver` and make sure you listen for it.

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` you declare a `BroadcastReceiver`

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And in your `MyReceiver` class you can do whatever you want to do, like for instance restarting your service.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ...
    }
}
```